# "Temporary value dropped while borrowed" error after using unwrap()

Tags: rust

In the following code, sometimes I only need the first `Keymap` produced by `get_keymaps()`. So I figured I could use `first()`. However, I found out it returns an `Option<&T>`, so I had to use `unwrap()` to get the value inside.

```
#[derive(Debug, Default)]
pub struct Keymap {
    pub key: char,
    pub command: String,
    pub description: String,
    pub prompt: Option<String>,
}

impl Keymap {
    pub fn new<S: AsRef<str>>(key: char, command: S) -> Self {
        let command = command.as_ref().to_owned();
        let description = command.clone();

        Self {
            key,
            command,
            description,
            ..Default::default()
        }
    }
}

fn get_keymaps<'a>() -> Vec<Keymap> {
    vec![Keymap::new('t', "echo 'test'")]
}

fn handle_keymap(keymap: &Keymap) {
    println!("Do something with {:?}", keymap);
}

fn main() {
    let keymap = get_keymaps().first().unwrap();
    handle_keymap(keymap);
}
```

[Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=e2d9f646660d941b99db20e7f44f8338)

But now I'm getting the following error:

```
error[E0716]: temporary value dropped while borrowed
  --> src/main.rs:33:18
   |
33 |     let keymap = get_keymaps().first().unwrap();
   |                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^                 - temporary value is freed at the end of this statement
   |                  |
   |                  creates a temporary value which is freed while still in use
34 |     handle_keymap(keymap);
   |                   ------ borrow later used here
```

I don't quite understand why a temporary value was freed. I'm not very sure what it means. And I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: The call to `get_keymaps` creates a temporary that doesn't outlive the assignment statement. But `first` borrows from that temporary so it too can't outlive the assignment. You need to assign the value `get_keymaps()` returns to a variable that outlives the use of `keymap`.

Comment: @isaactfa Oh, I think this worked: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=b56d58cd07484166a65d6466bf288d5a. Maybe post a short answer with a brief explanation?

Comment: Also the lifetime annotation `<'a>` on the `get_keymaps` function is not used and can be removed...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can imagine that something like

```
let keymap = get_keymaps().first().unwrap();
```

actually looks like this:

```
let keymap = {
    let temporary = get_keymaps();
    temporary.first().unwrap()
};
```

The call to `first` borrows from `temporary` but `temporary` gets dropped at the end of the block, i.e. the assignment statement. But when you want to use the reference created by `first` later, it forces `temporary` to outlive that use causing the compile error. By hoisting the assignment to `temporary` out of the assignment to `keymap`, you can create a value that lives long enough (exactly like the compiler message says):

```
let longer_lived_value = get_keymaps();
let keymap = longer_lived_value.first().unwrap();
```

Note that the same thing doesn't apply to the call to `unwrap`. That's because unlike `first`, which takes `self` by reference, `unwrap` takes `self` by value, taking ownership of the temporary instead of borrowing from it.